# Undo a revision

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks, ethics

I was just curious, if I make an edit, then realize that my edit made a question or answer to be incorrect: is there a way to revert back to the original other than editing it again, back to the original text?

Comment: Do you mean - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. See the below picture for a guide on the rollback feature:

[image]

In essence, this button will immediately revert to the edit that it is placed under.

Comment: Or: click "edit" in that revision, to be allowed to [type an edit comment for the rollback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back/41954#41954) as well.

Comment: @Arjan true, the "rollback" is shortcut for editing to that revision without edit summary.