# I am not granted to rollback an edit, but could I at least easily suggest a rollback?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edits, rollbacks

On Programmers.SE I noticed an edit by a user of 4K reputation that I feel changes the meaning of the original question ([Revision 2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/134194/revisions)) and I would have liked to roll back. However having not enough reputation here, my only possibility has been to click on “source”, copy the source block, and make a suggested edit with the contents of the original revision.

It would be IMO convenient for users that don't have enough reputation to have a way to indicate that they find an edit is not valid.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, as for the example: I feel that the edit did *not* change the meaning of the question. Also, instead of rolling back, you could have at least kept the improved formatting?

Comment: @Arjan: As you told whether that edit changed the meaning of the question is another debate (but I consider there is a difference between what is meant by “portable application” and “mobile edition of a software”. Regarding the improved formatting I must confess that I was quick, but the original formatting is not *that* bad.

Comment: I stand corrected, Benoit, I totally missed that one word that was changed, which indeed changed the meaning. Still then, the system does allow for reverting it just like you did; I don't see the need for "suggest rollback", but apparently others do.

Comment: @Benoit You need to clarify in the question what you mean by "portable application" as opposed to a mobile application or mobile optimized web site. The reason for the original edit is that your question is too ambiguous to be answered properly.

Comment: @Jarrod, it was not Benoit's question...

Comment: @Arjan I see that now. Although why is this meta question on Stackoverflow when this is a Programmers.SE issue???

Comment: @Jarrod Because it's a feature request for a network-wide feature.  (Suggested rollbacks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to do it without copy-pasting the original:

- Go back to the question
- Go to the edit page
- Select previous revision in the combo box that lists revisions
- provide a reason for rolling back

Comment: This looks to be the best solution -- allowing you suggest a rollback without having to do major editing or copy-pasting or forgo the entry of an edit reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as a suggested edit and post the reason for your edit.

Looking at the question, it looks like this is exactly what you have done and that it was accepted.

Comment: Also, editing (suggested edits included) is [the only way to leave an edit comment with a rollback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back).

Answer (score -2):

I've looked at the original and mine and I don't see a difference in meaning - only in wording and clarity.

I felt that your question was somewhat obscure and not worded very well - can you explain to me how it changed the nature of the question? I wasn't trying to hijack your question, only trying to make it more easily understood by the general community.

Comment: See Benoit's comment below the question: it was about the term "portable" versus "mobile". Still then, it was just an example for the feature request of course.

Comment: Glad you found this but this should really be a comment since it does not address the problem we are speaking of! That's not my question  (asker is [this stacker](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/35231/samridhi); however I left an answer on it). I feel there is a huge difference between a “portable application” (check on portableapps.com for example) and an application for mobile devices. Re-read both versions with that in mind and you'll probably understand why I said it changed the meaning.