# Do reviewers see when a suggested edit is a rollback?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rollbacks

As a user without full editing permission, I cannot do a roll-back myself. Instead, I need to have the rollback reviewed by [selecting a previous revision and suggesting that as edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121826/191131).

I was wondering how such a suggested edit is shown to the reviewers: Is it obvious to the reviewers that my suggested edit is based on a previous revision? If not, I probably need to put this information into the edit summary. If yes, can the reviewers easily see what I changed compared to the base revision, or is the suggested edit shown as diff to the latest revision?

The background of this question is the following: In a question of the type "What does this error message mean", the original poster added a word in error message in question: That either meant that he changed his setup compared to the original question (making it a different question), or that he was randomly editing the error message (making the question invalid). I wanted to revert this edit, so I chose the second last revision, explained the change in the comment, and proposed it. The change was rejected as too minor - which made me think that the reviewers didn't realize that the change was a rollback, but instead saw it as me wanting to remove a single word in the question. This is why I'm asking this question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, without an explicit comment, reviewers cannot see that your suggested edit is a rollback. Such an edit would look just like any other edit and could easily be rejected as too minor / radical / inappropriate.

An explicit edit note along the lines of `Rollback to revision [number]` would be helpful, perhaps with some extra information about *why* you are rolling back an edit. Submit and cross your fingers the reviewers are paying attention!

Comment: When you press the rollback button though, as opposed to just manually doing the opposite of what was done before, it adds the edit comment: "rollback to revision X".

Comment: @Servy: Sure, but those don't have to go through the review queue.

Comment: @Servy: And users without full editing privileges cannot use the rollback button on other posts but their own.

Answer (score 3):

You can put in the edit description::

> Rollback to revision x

Then they know that the edit was a rollback over a plain ol' edit.

Other than that, they just have to go off what you edited, and if they want to *dig* deeper they can look into if it was a rollback or not.