# Why was this edit rolled back?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I proposed an edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4811089/revisions) which was approved, but the initial answerer rolled it back with no explanation.

I'm happy for it to be rolled back if there was a flaw in my answer, but I would like to learn from my mistake so I don't make it again.

Additionally, how should a new user that *can't* comment determine why their edit was reverted?

Comment: I think I approved this edit, but I shouldn't have :). Action is more generic/abstract than AbstractAction and therefore the better choice. I misread the edit: I thought AbstractAction was more abstract than Action.

Comment: With regards to your second question: participate on the site well enough to gain enough rep to comment. Then you can inquire in a friendly manner about the reason. It's really not all that hard to gain enough rep to comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your edit was wrong. The code was correct in the first version (it is creating an instance of the concrete class and storing it in an variable declared as the interface class - which is correct).

The fact that it was approved by two other users is important (they should have spotted the error or left it alone if they didn't understand), but mistakes happen. The OP would have been notified of the edit which led to it being rolled back.

Obviously there's no edit summary box for a rollback so there's not a lot that can be done to explain why it was reverted. Though [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41954/59303) explains how you can leave an edit - by selecting "edit" on the revision you want to roll back to. It's not a well known feature so you can't expect everyone to use it when they roll back.

Certainly re-editing without more research is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. If I had enough rep I would have commented on the answer. Is it appropriate to create meta questions in this situation?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back) suggests it is possible to add a rollback edit summary.

Comment: @Daniel - that's news to me! It needs to be better publicised.

Comment: I've changed my question and accepted this answer. Thanks for shedding some light on the situation :) I'll be more careful with my edits in future (Eclipse had claimed the initial code war incorrect, but clearly this was not the case).