# Rollback reason message

Tags: feature-request, notifications, rollbacks, edit-summary

In order of importance:

1. Add a reason field for rollback
2. Notify the author of the edit that's being rolled back of the rollback and the reason
3. Notify the approvers of the edit too (if they exist due to editor's low reputation) of the rollback and the reason

A few times after I've received edit notifications for answer of mine, which other users have (incorrectly!) approved, I have then rolled back the edit, because the edit was in fact wrong. I really wanted to add a message for *why* the edit was rolled back.

Why isn't there a field to add a (optional) message for why the edit is being rolled back, similar to the "Edit summary" field for an edit?

In addition to the message field, I really wanted the other user to be notified about the roll back, *and* notify tell the users who approved the edit (if any), so they are more careful in the future.

Comment: Completely agree, this would also solve the problem of rejecting a bad edit through the queue, only to find out it was already approved by robo-reviwers or inexperienced ones.

Answer (score 4):

Such events are not very common and I wouldn't consider this feature essential. You can already do this by manually editing the post, it's just a *bit* harder. When you want to rollback an approved edit, you can use the following work-around:

- Go to the *Revisions* history for that answer
- Find the Revision before the incorrect edit -- i.e. the most meaningful revision
- Click on the *Edit* link
- Type the reason for rollback in the *Edit Summary* field
- Save the edit

Example revision history:

[image: Screenshot]

See also:

- [Could we be permitted to provide a reason for rolling back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back)

Comment: Does this address OPs' bullets #2 and #3?

Comment: Well, how about if you _had_ to write a few words when rolling back? Right now, IIANM, you don't.