# Is it possibly to send a message to a user who edited a question / answer?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I know is not possible to send a personal message to another user. What I would like to do would be to inform a user that I am rolling back an edit he made and explain him the reasons for doing so. But in this specific case, the user didn't write any comment or answer to the question, so I do not have a way to communicate with him. Is it possibly to send a message to a user who edited a question / answer?

Note: I know there exists [a way to specify the reason of rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back).

Comment: You can notify them with @username; except you won't get the convenience of auto-fill.

Comment: quoting from @NormalHuman's link: `Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions).` (Who can be notified).

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks, exactly because of the missing autofill I thought he wouldn't be notified.