# Adding summary to tag-only rollback doesn't work

Tags: bug, tags, rollbacks, edit-summary

It's possible to add an edit summary to a rollback:
[Could we be permitted to provide a reason for rolling back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41953/295232)

However, this doesn't seem to be working when you rollback a tag-only edit. [Here](https://youtu.be/pi-SUMcLOYc) is a YouTube video demonstrating the problem (it's too long to inline it as a GIF); and I've just tried it on the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) as well.

Comment: The grace period doesn't apply for any sort of rollback.

Comment: Ah, true. I've removed that from the title since it's still a bug ...

Comment: Confirmed. Also *manually* changing the Tags back the way they were (within the Grace Period) is counted by the System as a Rollback; and your edit is blocked, though the 'grace period rollback' is recorded in the History. (Probably inter-related). [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJSTw.png).

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3122/451