# Custom rollback reason not displayed on the Activity page

Tags: bug, recent-activity, rollbacks, edit-summary

When providing a [custom rollback reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back), it displays properly when looking at the [timeline](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/98622/timeline#history_81d0346f-01c2-4ad2-b1f3-62597ee4a279) and [revision history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/98622/revisions), but not the [Activity page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble?tab=activity) ("[All Actions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble?tab=activity&sort=all)" or "[Revisions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble?tab=activity&sort=revisions)"). Compare:

> Rollback to Revision 1 - removed self-promotion

> rolled back to a previous revision

While the second is technically accurate, it seems like it should respect my decision to explain the rollback.

Comment: The linked example is my Puzzling user's most recent action (to make it easier for other people to see an instance of the bug), but once I do something else with that account it'll slide down the page.