# Can we put more detail into the descriptions of badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Some of the badges (e.g. *cleanup*) do not have readily understandable descriptions.  (What is a rollback, in terms of SE?)  I automatically think to click on a badge I don't understand, to learn more, but the only additional info I get on the badge is who recently earned it.  Could we expound a little in the page that comes up when we click the badge?  So I don't have to ask on meta what it means?

**Edit:** I see this is partly a duplicate.  But what I don't see answered is why we don't just put the full descriptions on the individual badge pages?  It seems clunky to have to search for a meta question to find what we want.  Even with this [question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), I still don't understand what the *cleanup* badge means.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of that *"recently awarded to"* page is the badge name *and* its [description](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/4/cleanup). That description *also* appears next to each badge listed on the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges).

If you have a better description for that badge, this is a great place to suggest it. We are constantly updating and clarifying the help guidance and descriptions throughout the system.

But I might respectfully suggest that "rollback" is easy to understand once it comes into use — at +2,000 reputation when you can edit posts. There are a *lot* of features which unfold as you continue to use the system. It is not always reasonable to explain all bells and whistles about the system before becomes relevant to that user. It would make the system seem too daunting.

Not that we haven't tried:

[**Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Comment: Does "rollback" mean that you delete your post?

Comment: @drm65 See [What is a 'rollback'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038).

Comment: Or the glossary I linked: **Rollback** - Occurs when a user edits a question, and selects one of the older edits from the revision history to paste back into the question, effectively undoing any edits made subsequent to the selected revision. The complete edit history is still preserved.