# Discard a suggested edit before it's accepted in peer review

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Should there be an option to discard an suggested edit to a question or answer before it is accepted in peer review?

I saw a badly formatted and non-edited question, edited it and saved my changes for peer review as I don't have the required rights yet. I refreshed my browser, and oh dear, oh my, someone with enough privileges had just edited it too! And their edit was much better than mine was.

My suggested edit went into queue and a few minutes later someone accepted it. My edit was much better than the original (formatted code) but the other edit was a great work of scrubbing (same code edit and text changes).

Naturally, when I saw the other edit, I tried to remove my pending edit. It just wasn't possible.

**EDIT**

Here's the question I edited: [C++ max/min element in an array without knowing array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104606/c-highest-array)

Comment: Hehee, really funny, "edit", "random". :)

Comment: Are you saying the edit did not capture your feature request as intended?

Comment: Well, it is a better one for sure. However, I'm not a native English speaker and the line "work of scrubbing" is unfamiliar to me. It sounds.. well, odd to me. Perhaps it is a synonym for great work in English? It seems I misinterpreted it, my apologies if I did so.

Answer (score 1):

You can already [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) which is a quite similar feature so I'm not sure it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went back to the previously mentioned question and tried to find the rollback feature. It's not there? Does it become available when you get direct editing privileges?

Comment: I took a closer look into the rollback FAQ. It says the feature is only available when you have the editing rights. That means users who don't have those privileges do not have means of discarding their own saved edits before they go public.