# how to accept or reject review?

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

I want to know how I can accept or reject reviews of my questions or answers?
I can see my question has been reviewed or edited but I found nowhere to reject them or accept new ones!

**edit:**
Look at [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback). but I can not see any **rollback** on my edited question.why?

Comment: It's by design. You can't.

Comment: Am I the only one confused about what the issue is here? It looks like he's asking about suggested edits, in which case the FAQ says [he totally can accept/reject them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284).

Comment: @lunboks - that's only whilst it's still pending, which I thought was reasonably clear on the FAQ too

Comment: @awoodland I know. It's not like you can't see pending suggested edits on your own posts.

Comment: @lunboks Not easily, though, since you'd have to manually check every thing you've ever posted.

Comment: Only users with full edit privs will see a rollback link. However, if you want to roll back a revision, you can open the editor and select the revision you want using the dropdown at the top of the editor (above the title line, if present).

Comment: Can you clarify: Is your question about rollbacks or about suggested edits?

Comment: @Jason  first it was about suggested edtits, then I added new one! thanks, I got my answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not up to you.  Please see the FAQ on editing at the link below:

[How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)