# What should be done when a user edit a question to remove it?

Tags: discussion, edits, too-localized

I answered a question and the user accepted my answer but then he edited the question to replace it with... something that is not a question.

Should I edit back the question?

(Although in this specific case, the question seems to be **too localized** and I flagged it accordingly.)

Comment: Can you give a link to the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863645/menu-stuck-in-ie7-ie8-suckerfish I rolled it back already.

Answer (score 9):

[Roll it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback), or, if you don't have the sufficient privileges to roll back revisions, leave a comment asking the OP to restore the content, and flag it for moderator attention.

In this case I've rolled back the vandalism for you; and you're right, it's also too localized, so I've closed it accordingly as well.

Comment: I'm also concerned about the user, shouldn't we warn him or something?

Comment: I've left a comment on his question.