# How can I cancel an editing on my answer?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, edits, rejected-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a ‘rollback’?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)

Some guy has edited my answer, which I wrote about half an a year ago and was upvoted by many people who were helped by this answer.

I want my answer to stay the same as it was before the the editing because now it doesn't reflect my correct meaning.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: That duplicate link should tell you all that you need to know about rolling back an edit.

Comment: You can roll back. The edit contained valuable info though. (About IE9) Consider preserving it.