# Can other users revert the edit of the original poster?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

I stumbled across this question where the original poster [edited her own question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17713567/revisions) to replace the entire content of the question with multiple "**delete**" words. This change has been reverted by another user.

Is this a correct action to take?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback

Comment: Ha ha, looks like someone wanted to have his homework done for him and then tried to delete the question so that teacher couldn't google for it :)

Comment: Not just the linked question either, all four of their still existent questions had the same vandalism and then rollback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - revisions can be rolled back by people who don't own the post.

And the rollback can indeed include changes by the post owner.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification. I would have expected the owners decision would be binding, similar to the edit review.

Comment: @bummi It can't be, because they could decide to vandalize their own content, as in this case. We need some way of handling that. (But yes, *normally*, you should let edits by the post owner stand and refrain from rolling them back.)