# How to revoke a suggested edit?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

While trying to update (by editing) my answer, I accidentally edited another answer and submitted the edit. A message told me that the edit wouldn't be visible until it was peer reviewed.

How  can I revoke the edit I made?

Comment: It happened something similar to me once. The edit was approved. Then, I suggested another edit (the way it was originally) and I apologized with the reviewers and author's answer in the "edit summary" field.

Comment: @AndreSilva I should have done that..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't undo(revoke) your edit, once it got submitted.

It will be reviewed by the suggested edit reviewers or the owner of that post and if got approved, your edit to that post will be viewed to all others.

If you have more than 2000 reputations, you can [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) your edit or any others edit.

Comment: Confirmed it's not possible to revoke suggested edit, if you edit again before it's reviewed back to original contents, you'll get "Nothing appears to have changed" message. @Bart FYI as well.