# Review a suggested edit to my post so that I can accept or decline it

Tags: discussion, edits

I think there should be a way for the user to review and accept the Edit from someone else.

If I am willing to ask a question for example, if somebody else hasn't understood it, edited the question and thereby diverted the topic, I should be allowed to review the 'suggested' edit and accept it or decline it if need be, right?

Comment: and your question is...

Comment: Any reason you can't edit again? Or rollback the revision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mandatory approval from OP would not be good for the quality of content on Stack Exchange. Sometimes there are minor layout corrections (like code formatting), for such items you would agree that OP's approval would be an overkill. Rarely posts contain hateful/offensive text which should be edited without waiting for a moderator's intervention.

When a post is edited, OP is notified (screenshot below)
[image]

After going through the suggested edit, OP can approve or reject the edit (no further approve/reject vote is required). If a suggested edit has already become part of the post and if OP disagrees then the edit can be [rolled back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) which reverts a questions (or answer) back to a previous version in the edit history.

Answer (score 4):

Why, it's already here. You should have a read of this [topic on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) which covers off pretty much everything regarding editing.

Answer (score 3):

The users who ask a question are notified of any edit made for their own questions (maybe this happens when their reputation is higher than a threshold), and they can decline the suggested edit with a single vote, even on Stack Overflow, where three users giving the same vote are required.

Even in the case users are not notified of any suggested edit, from the question page is visible when there is a pending suggested edit, since the *edit* link becomes *edit (1)*.

Answer (score 2):

You can "reject" an edit by rolling it back.  When a question is edited, you will see a second user's ID under the question.  Click where it says "Edited XXX Ago" (where XXX is a timespan):

> [image]

And you have the choice to roll back the edit:

> [image]

Comment: Hope I wasn't too overzealous with my screenshot... feel free to rollback, lol! ;)