# Misusing edit options for users with reputation of 2000+

Tags: support, reputation, edits

Assume that a user with 2000+ reputation (whose edits are applied immediately and don't need approval) by mistake or intentionally edits a good question or answer and just puts rubbish instead.

Can the original answer or question be restored?
How does Stack Overflow detect this kind of people to revoke their edit privilege?

The reason I'm asking is that I like Stack Overflow's system that allows experienced users to moderate the site. I'd like to use a similar system in my own website that I'm currently developing but I'm afraid some users may misuse the privileges they are given.

Comment: You can always roll it back..

Comment: Part of your concerns are answered here: [What is a rollback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 2000+ users, there is a "rollback" link for each edit in the revision history. Clicking it restores a post to its form at that revision, effectively undoing any edits made.

If you ever see this happen intentionally and you think the user has done this multiple times, flag for moderator attention.

If you have 2000+ reputation, feel free to roll it back yourself. If you don't, a flag will take care of it.

Comment: well I have the reputation. I'm concerned about finding these kind of people. not just rollbaking a single post that one may have ruined.

Comment: @Ashkan Rest assured, these people are not terribly common, nor generally very intelligent about hiding the vandalism. Since edits bump posts, we generally catch them quickly.

Comment: the reason I'm concerned a lot is that in my country having improper content in my website may lead to website banning and I'm trying to avoid this. thank you for your answer. I think I won't give instant edit privilege to anybody :)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani The main mechanism Stack Exchange uses to ensure quality content *is* peer editing - just like Wikipedia. In truth, I haven't seen one misuse of edit privs by a 2ker.

Comment: @Undo you are right. but as I said in our country improper content may lead to site banning and when a website is good these conditions make some competitors do stupid things to get rid of your website.

Answer (score 3):

This is why edits bump posts to the front page: so everyone can review and spot vandalism. There's a rollback link easily available to undo bad edits. You can even flag the post if you think a moderator needs to contact the user.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that users who have been around for a while are familiar with the site, and they can take responsible and appropriate actions.

That's why privileges are gained with reputation, and that's also why a daily reputation cap exist: having a hight reputation usually means that you've an active user for long enough to know how the community works, and you didn't just post a lucky answer/question which attracted a lot of upvotes.

While this might occasionally not hold true, there's an underlying trust granted to users, which increases with reputation.

That being said, we're [humans after all](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4e94y4EjWGs) and that's why the [rollback feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) of post edits exists.