# How to restrict someone from editing my post?

Tags: discussion, edits, question-restrictions

I had recently asked a question on Stack Overflow and a few people had edited my question which was distorting the information provided by me. How can I restrict a post to be edited by others?

Comment: Hmm. It appears that you had taken issue with the backslashes at the beginning of some lines, correct? If I'm reading the revision history correctly, those backslashes were in the first revision of the question.

Comment: And its hilarious that people ask their doubts about understanding how to work better with Stack Overflow and other sites and here also people down vote the questions. Obviously I don't know something that's why posted a question here. Is my question really so stupid?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259834/how-to-make-a-statement-starting-with-not-considered-as-a-comment-in-an-sql) what you are talking about? All the edits by others looks fine by me, they are trying to put the code in a good format. The backslash was not edited out, but it's understandable, as it's in the original post.

Comment: @MKSingh, as explained [in my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211216/209637), the concept of collaborative editing is discussed both on the [about] page, and in the [help] in the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If you are truly interested in learning about how to work better on the Stack Exchange sites, reading the help would be a good place to start and may very well explain the downvotes.

Comment: You may be seeing downvotes, MK Singh, because people dispute assumptions in your question (*...distorting the information provided by me...*), as a few folks here have mentioned.

Comment: @jmac: Okay ... I got it.

Comment: It seems he has a point in complaining about the edits though.  I have no idea what went through those users' minds, as far as I can see they modified the original code?

Comment: Oh indeed, the backslashes where there from the start. Then I don't see  what your gripe is, MK Singh.

Comment: The edits were pretty "meh" from what I can see, but your answer is still below.

Answer (score 5):

> Q. How can I restrict a post to be edited by others?

You cannot restrict editing. But one possible undo mechanism is the [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) which you already seem to know(as seen from the [question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20259834/revisions)).

Also, if you feel that a lot of other users are editing your posts inappropriately, then you can raise a custom flag on that post to a moderator, explain the moderator very clearly what is going on, and if the moderators thinks that there is some wrong editing going on, they can lock your post, so that no more edits would be allowed to it.

---

> Q.  a few people had edited my question which was distorting the information provided by me.

I feel that in your case, [I'm guessing you're referring this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20259834/2024761), the edits were made just to make your post a bit more readable. Agreed that they weren't great edits, but none of it seemed to *distort the information provided by you*.

The thing with the backslashes is that the very first version of your question itself had the backslashes. They just brought it to the limelight while formatting the question. Click on the *source* link on the first version in the history of that question and you can see the question as a raw text. It already had the backslashes.

Comment: Yes you are correct and yes they did make a few changes in the formatting of text and I always welcome that but they had changed the very question ,i.e., the query which was giving me problem. How can they decide that whether that query was giving me problem or the query which they think...

Comment: @MKSingh - I don't see any of the edits making any changes to the query in your question or something. All they have done is added some formatting and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for throwing some light on this. I will try your suggestion. Wanted to upvote your answer but don't have enough reputation. Thanks anyway..

Comment: They had added back slashes (/) in  the lines starting with a '#' in my query.

Comment: No, they didn't, @MK Singh. You added them, in the first version of the question. Go to [the revisions page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20259834/revisions), and click "source" on version 1. [Here's the raw source of the first version you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9025a82d-0777-4745-9936-2e2b33b8a141/view-source).

Comment: @MKSingh - If you look at those edits in the history carefully, you can see that the very first version of your question itself had the backslashes. They just brought it to the limelight while formatting the question. Click on *source* in the first version of the history and see the question as a raw text. It already had the backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange is a network of Collaboratively Edited sites.

On the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it says:

> Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.
>
> > *Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.*

See also the [Help Center on Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> ### Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?
>
> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!
>
> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

<sup>Note: Editing code is a bit different and has [slightly different rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), but is still encouraged</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't. What you can do, however, is roll back the question revision.

Comment: Okay. But I have already tried that. After I rollback again someone else changed it.

Comment: You can flag your own question for moderator attention, asking them to lock the question. In this particular case though, you had been the one to add the backslashes (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9025a82d-0777-4745-9936-2e2b33b8a141/view-source)