# What's wrong with my answer?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I tried to post answer in this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211210/how-to-restrict-someone-from-editing-my-post#autocomment678534), but it is posted as comment and not as answer. Whats wrong with this? and I tried three time, all are posted as comments.  If you check that comments, It clearly shows the format that I made it through the editor.

Comment: Below the 3 auto-posted comments, I saw this message *Trivial answer converted to comment*. I guess that's why it was auto-converted to a comment from an answer because the system felt that your answer was *Trivial*.

Comment: The system thinks your answer is too trivial. Try adding some more context and it should go through.

Comment: @animuson now I need to ask one more question, how he posted the answer after it marked as duplicate ? (I'm talking about the below post check the time)

Comment: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed)

Answer (score 1):

As far I know under some conditions like a short answer and possible some more conditions answers are automatically converted to comments.

Maybe that had worked if you had wrote a second sentence. Even if I post a stub answer I always two sentences.