# Someone edited my post - how can I tell what they did and why?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have a number of issues with the concept of editing other peoples' posts, but this is a key concern (one of two, actually).

- How can I tell who edited my post and why it was edited?
- Do others see who has made edits?
- What happens if I reverse those edits?
- Is there an automatic way to do that or do I have to manually re-edit?

Comment: First you get notified when someone edits your post. Second click on the edit time in your post to see the post history. Third: You can rollback edits you don't like

Comment: There must be a FAQ that explains all this? Well [What is a 'rollback'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) is one part. Also see [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Comment: I improved the formatting and grammar a bit, but didn't add [faq-proposed]; if anyone's comfortable doing that I would agree. (@Martin)

Comment: Also, how ironic ;)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow - It is pretty much all covered already in "How does editing work". If I had the rep to VTC as dupe I would. If any info is missing from that answer surely best to add it there.

Comment: @MartinSmith getting notified of edits made to your posts isn't mentioned in that faq... all in all there are too many subjects here so we can't really close as dupe.

Comment: @gnat good point, having it closed as dupe of all three will make total sense. Joint effort wins! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Agreed! This is one thing I don't like about coming along a post like this as a diamond mod; if I make a dupe vote, the question I choose overrides all others entered. Often, I would prefer something like how it works with all users.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn yep, I once considered starting feature request asking to let moderators choose multiple dupe sources... don't remember why I ditched the idea though.

Answer (score 12):

As a general note - the Stack Exchange model has been **specifically** written to allow such edits - this is **not** a problem or a bug - it is by design.

---

Now, to your questions:

> how can i tell what they did and why?

Click on the `edited <relative time> ago` link. You will see all revisions.

> [image]

The revision should have a summary too - should tell you why.

> do others see who has made edits?

Yes.

> what happens if I reverse those edits (and is there an automatic way to do that or do I have to manually re-edit?

You **can** rollback (link on the revision you wish to rollback to), **but** - make sure not to rollback changes that improve the post. Rollback wars are frowned upon.

Comment: And from the revisions page, you can choose to Rollback to any past revision, no need to "manually re-edit".

Comment: @ShadowWizard - was adding. Thanks.

Comment: Jon Skeet style, love it!

Comment: @ShadowWizard - learned from the master ;)

Comment: Rollback wars also raise automatic flag and good chance moderator will come over and lock the post in such a case.

Comment: The rollback feature is only available to users with full editing privileges though.

Answer (score 5):

Also important to mention that for non trivial edits (title or body >6 characters change) you get notification to your inbox:

> [image]

Clicking that inbox item will take you directly to the Revisions page.

Comment: Thanks everyone.   Some points made by several of you so I wont address individuals.  Clicking on the time of edit to display the changes ... is that supposed to be intuitive?  IMNSHO its not very intuitive.   Certainly I can see that roll back wars would be very bad and have no intention of starting one.   This leads to a separate topic which I'm staying away from right now (this is not Wikipedia as our posts are not anonymous) .. I want to read more before I get into that.

Comment: WOW.   I just went back and looked at the post in question.   People have time to correct others typo / spelling etc?  Im really impressed.  Its like having a secretary.

Comment: Oh; I didn't know those notifications don't show up for very small edits. Interesting!

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn "don't flood the inbox with noise" is still a strong motto, I tend to agree with it. :-)

Comment: Strange. *My* motto is, "beat the owner of each inbox over the head with bags full of unicorn horns until they submit"...