# Rolling back not really rolling back?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks, edit-badges

I've just edited my post and I saw this in the corner:

[image: Warning!]

I did not receive the rollback badge for this.
But how can it display me it will be a rollback, but it won't count for a rollback?

Comment: Key word is **effectively**

Comment: True rollback is when you click the "rollback" link in the post revision list. Otherwise it's just and edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You edited an old revision of the post, you did not actually perform a rollback.  As OGHaza astutely [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216082/rolling-back-not-really-rolling-back#comment699066_216082), the keyword in that message is **"effectively"**.

You get a Clean Up badge when you perform your first rollback, not your first edit that is similar to a rollback.

To rollback (and hence be qualified for the Clean Up badge), you actually need to click the rollback link

[image]

To get the rollback link, you need to access the revision history of the post by clicking the "edited X min ago" link to the left of your user card:

> [image]

But the link won't show up unless the post has more than 1 revision, and you have full edit privileges on the post in question, meaning:

- you are the owner of the post
- have 2K rep
- have 100 rep and the post in question is Community Wiki.

> See also the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)

Comment: Additional question, when is that button visible?

Comment: I believe it doesn't show up unless you have full edit privileges on the post, meaning it is one of your own posts or you have 2K rep.

Comment: Alright, I have 1200+ points on SO, but never seen a button like that. Not on my own question or answer, that's why I wondered why my "rollback" didn't work. Thanks

Comment: @Robuust you obviously need multiple revisions to a post to rollback too.  Since ShadowWizard edited your question, you should see the rollback link when you view the revisions of this question.

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246839/export-and-import-xlsx-in-c-sharp-table-error Where should I see my button, as I truly cannot find it.

Comment: @Robuust you have to view the revisions of the post.  For that specific question, the page is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19246839/revisions).  To get there, you have to click the "edited X mins ago" link to the left of your user card under your question.  I have edited a screenshot into my answer for you