# how to contest edit

Tags: discussion, edits

I wrote:

[cross platform compilation and installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874533/cross-platform-compilation-and-installers)

someone did edit it. English is not my mother tongue. So I have no problem being corrected. I'm happy to learn. But changing:

"assume you wrote" into "assume you written" is totally wrong. And my colleague ( a British person, well educated, software engineer and reading 1000 pages every week in his mother tongue ) confirms that this edit was very awkward.

Is there a way to contest edits from other members ?

Comment: I don't think so, but for something like that, you can also correct it in another edit.

Comment: Just... edit it yourself??

Comment: Sure, but I would like also to write to the person who edited it to make sure it was not a typo, etc...

Comment: It's also possible to roll back to an earlier version. To do so, click on the timestamp of the edit to go to the edit history, the scroll down to the version you want to roll back to, and click "rollback".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit has passed, it is there now, you can add your own edit to it to fix/revert things.

I must say that I would consider this edit too minor though. If you feel strongly about it then you could signal this to moderators (custom flag option) but that's up to you (personally I would look through his history first to determine if it's a pattern or a one-time mistake).

If you wish to contact the user, you can do so by placing a comment and typing `@<username>`. Editors are also included in the list of people you can notify with this.

Comment: Flagging for a moderator to what end?

Comment: I do not want to create trouble for a person who spend a lot of time answering to the community on its spare time. It is just an inadequate edit. He wanted to help. I'll let him know.

Comment: @user2346536 glad you aren't going to flag, that is bad advice.  A single typo in a single edit is not worth bothering a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like a portion of the specific edit to your own post, then just edit it yourself to fix it.  Or if you don't like the entire edit, then [roll it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) to the previous revisions.

For a single issue, that's it, there's really nothing else to do.

There are thousands and thousands of users across the site with varying degrees of competency in English.  Some are native speakers, some have minimal English skills, and plenty that fall in the middle somewhere, so we can't expected everyone to make perfect edits.  That's what the editing system is there for, so someone else can fix the typos and mistakes of others.

As for contacting the user, I suggest you don't as there is virtually nothing good that can become of it, and if he becomes insulted, then you can have another situation on your hand.

I'd also avoid flagging the post.  A single typo in and edit is certainly not worth bothering a moderator about and the flag would almost certainly be declined.

That being said, if the same user comes back and tries to make the same edit to undo your correction, that's when you need to stop and step away.  You don't want to get into an edit or rollback war with someone, especially over something so trivial as which version of the past tense of "write" to use.

If you do end up in an edit war with someone, now is the time to flag for a moderator as they will step in an deal with the user.  Select "Other" and explain the situations briefly but completely and they will make edit, contact the user, and if necessary lock the post to prevent further edits (although this would only be done in extreme cases).