# What do you do when someone (obviously) erroneously edits your answer?

Tags: discussion

Today someone accidentally edited one of my answers (he thought he was editing his own).  He quickly noticed his error and reverted it, but it left me thinking:  What should I have done if he hadn't noticed his error?

Comment: Roll back the edit and move on. Nothing more really. Leaving comment to the editor is possible too (using `@name`) asking why he did it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback

Comment: Rollback Rollback Rollback Go have a Beer!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Mind making that answer an answer?

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO; this isn't deliberate vandalism that needs to be dealt with as such, this is a mistake.