# Please reword the "rollback" link

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, rollbacks

In a post's revision history, every time I go to rollback an edit, I have to scroll up and down to figure out whether the link means "rollback this revision" or "rollback *to* this revision" (eventually accomplished by determining and then promptly forgetting, for the fifth time this week, that the most recent revision has no "rollback" link; thus, the latter meaning is the only one possible).

[image: Screenshot of "rollback" link in post revision history]

Could you please tweak the text to make it immediately clear what action will be performed upon clicking "rollback"? *"rollback to here"* would be fine…

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is hover over the link to get text that says exactly what it is for:

[image: sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any "offensive" flags]

Comment: I'd still rather like the label itself to be clearer, actually. The tooltip is great, okay, but I don't like having to reveal hidden text to find out what a widget actually does when it's otherwise mortally ambiguous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So you do a quick search and find https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback.  Sure, it would be nice to have a more explicit link, but I don't see it as much of a problem.  Most important question of all: what do you suggest?

Comment: I do not wish to have to look up a question on meta every time I want to use that link. Is requesting a clearer GUI label really that bad? N.B. I'm not claiming that it's like the most important thing ever or anything. _"rollback to this/here"_ would be fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I looked it up once, and I never needed to again ... except for a couple minutes ago.  "Rollback to this" sounds fine to me, though, and would be easier to understand.  I think that the "Cleanup" badge definitely needs to be more explicit about what "rollback" is.  I don't think I found out what it was until I earned it.