# What is a "rollforward"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, rollbacks

What is a 'rollforward' on Stack Exchange sites? I haven't seen this mentioned but I do understand the term.

As for each OP of a *question* or *answer* there is the "rollback" option (FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback))... However, the "rollforward" option appears to be missing and there was no mention in FAQ about it.

How do I prevent double work if OP reverted to an earlier question/answer revision (by mistake)?

Why this question...

In the example below OP seems to correct a revision but there is no "rollforward" button. Making another edit for this OP and wasting "suggestion-review-time" of other users seem a bit far fetched...

> **SEE ALSO**
>
> *Image 1* : OP asking for another edit due to hilariousness or stupidity?
>
> *Image 2* : amount of "rollbacks".
>
> *Image3* : cannot find the "rollforward" option to go from revision 3 to rev 4 again.

...

*EDIT: answer in-short: based on below enlightening answers of *Rogue the Bat* and *rene* it appears to be locked under 2k rep threshold and you can only point OP in the right "rollback" revision direction.

Image 1:[image]

Image 2:[image]

Image 3:[image]

Comment: I’m really struggling to understand what you’re asking here

Comment: It seems the OP wants a way to undo rollbacks, but the title and post are fairly unclear.

Comment: @BigBadCat... spot on! ... I've modified question to anser Cai's comment.

Comment: @ZF007 if you're requesting a new feature then word it as a feature request; "What is a "rollforward" (and your first paragraph) isn't suggesting a new feature.

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense anyway, you *can* already rollback a rollback... *you* can't because you don't have editing privileges.

Comment: I did that with a twist of humor but some are just not ... how do I say this polite.... xyz .. to understand. Therefore I made the downvoter referal so they get the humor there for the 27 revisions of the "rollback" question, whic is kinda ROFLOL.... where is the glue..cus I keep falling off my chair.

Comment: Beware... Unclear humor costs rep.

Comment: I guess that needs a spoiler alert banner on top of it ... be my guest and suggest a modification... I'm all up for it to be a wiki soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roll back to revision 4. The rollback to revision 3 created it as a new revision (#5), meaning to go back to 4, roll back to 4. There is no rollforward because rollbacks create a new revision. It requires editing privileges to do though (or you have to be the OP)

**TL;DR:** rollback to revision 3 becomes revision 5, meaning 4 is a past revision. So roll back to that one.

---

You can basically consider a rollback as editing the content of the post with that of a previous edit.

Answer (score 1):

*Rollforward* already kind-of exist for users with full edit privileges (2K on Stack Overflow) or the OP:

[image]

You can click the rollback link on any revision to put in another revision with the source of the revision you selected.

In the case you described you better offered the OP to visit the source link of your revision, copy the markdown and apply it verbatim to their post.

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense. Also, adding the "rollforward" questionair to the help-centre, next to "whats a "rollback".