# I mistakenly approved a suggested edit. How can I undo it?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

My confused mind swapped old/new state in suggested edit and I've approved an edit that introduced rubbish when I was thinking I was approving an edit that removed rubbish.

How can I undo this?

Comment: Good news is that someone else rejected the edit, so the change did not take effect. Still it would be nice to know how to undo for future cases ; The item that someone attempted to vandalise is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639077/how-to-use-sys-exit-in-python/14639183#14639183

Comment: In addition to the information provided in the proposed duplicate, if your review approval made the suggested edit take effect, you can [roll it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/622284) and it'll be immediately reverted. Also, don't worry too much about it. We all make mistakes, and in this case, it is can be easily reverted if it slips through :)

Comment: @Spevacus Rolling it back would still leave the OP with the reputation for a successful edit suggestion. Since mods can reject the edit, sometimes it's better to flag for mod attention to get the edit reverted rather than rolling back.

Comment: Hi Dima! I briefly suspended you from reviewing on Stack Overflow because of your decision to approve that edit, but @Catija pointed me to this question where you admit to having made a mistake. I see no point in suspending you if you *know* that you made a mistake. As such, I've lifted your review suspension. In case you see that history showing up, now you'll know what happened.  Do try to exercise more care next time, since you now know that there is no "undo" option.

Comment: Flagging for mod intervention to override the approval is a great idea on most SE sites, but less ideal on Stack Overflow where the flag volume is so high. It might be days or even weeks before we get around to reviewing such a flag. So, you can pop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) and ask for the edit to be reviewed (and, thus, rejected) by other users. Do make sure to read [the chat room's FAQ](https://socvr.org/) first. Another good option is just to keep the tab open and refresh until you're sure it was handled correctly by your peers.