# Where is the text string "edit rollback" used in the system?

Tags: support, localization, transifex, follow-post

I found this [sentence](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15393) in Transifex:

> followed question — edit rollback

What does "edit rollback" mean in that context?

Comment: I guess it means a question you followed had an rollback to a previous revision

Comment: Here is a SEDE query with all rollbacks on SOru: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1382279 maybe you can find someone who followed one of those questions and then check if they have an inbox message that is the one you found in Transifex.

Comment: @rene if you follow this question we can check your guess when you ready.

Comment: The translation (according to Google Translate) seems OK. "отслеживаемый вопрос — откат правки" = "tracked issue - undo edits". ("Undo **last** edit" would be more accurate).

Comment: @Rob "Undo **last** edit" would not be more accurate. While a rollback must, inherently, undo the last edit, it may undo many edits, up to all of the edits which were made to the post (e.g. a rollback to revision 1 of 53). "Undo edit(s)" would cover more situations.

Comment: @Makyen, instead of pointing out what's wrong why not offer a correct and accurate translation - the concept of what is occurring must also be conveyed, not simply a naive word by word; we need a means to explain the ramifications of the action. While it may seem like an edit simply *goes back* there are penalties for the editor and records of such kept - this needs to fit into a minimum number of words.

Comment: @Rob I interpreted your comment as being about the concept which was being communicated, rather than specifically about how the translation which Google was providing should be interpreted. I read your comment as meaning that it would be more appropriate to translate "tracked issue - undo last edit", rather than "tracked issue - undo edits", which would *not* be the same concept, at least when expressed in English. I'd also note that there are no penalties to an editor when their edit is rolled back, nor are statistics kept about how many of someone's edits are rolled back.

Comment: Statistics are kept about how many of a user's edit suggestions are rejected, but that's not the same as having their edit involved in a rollback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)

Comment: [The rollback to the question did result in the "edit rollback" message](https://i.imgur.com/lRt9vA0.png)

Comment: I confirm the finding from @VLAZ : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMdr.png

Comment: @rene thanks. It’s time to post an answer.

Comment: @TheforestofReinstateMonica where in that question does it explain or show where the string / text is used? I can't find it, maybe I read over it.

Comment: @rene I was replying to the question contents, not the title (which is a little more confusing).

Comment: @TheforestofReinstateMonica it is not a dupe. For translations (notice the mention of transifex in the question) it is important to know where and how a string is used because that influences the translation. In transifex the translators don't have context so they need to rely on finding these texts in the English UI first so they can proper translate. It is never a matter of them not understanding how the site works.

Comment: @rene Fair enough. I've retracted my vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text string is used as message in the Inbox when a post you follow is rolled-back to a previous revision

Here is a screenshot of my inbox message and the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/361800/timeline) of this very question to indicate the relationship between events in the timeline and the inbox message:

[image]