# If several edits are made to a question and then it is subsequently rolled back to the original version, what happens to the history?

Tags: support

If the initial version is rolled back to become live then why would the intermediate revisions not remain in history?

Question in question: [How does the presumption of innocence apply to investigative interest by police?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98597/how-does-the-presumption-of-innocence-apply-to-investigative-interest-by-police)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)

Comment: Are you asking about a specific post that you forgot to link? Are you referring to grace period edits? I have no idea what you're asking about here.

Comment: @PeterJames not that I can tell, sadly no.

Comment: How quickly did you make the edits?

Comment: @Laurel fairly quickly as the purpose was to populate the history with various alternative forms of the question and let others weigh in on the best.

Comment: Please add screenshots showing us step by step what you did.

Comment: See: "[How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/271271)" In particular, see the parts regarding the grace period and rollbacks. Your comments on the question you linked imply that you made multiple edits. However, there are no revisions recorded for that question. This would have only happened if all of the edits you made were a single set of grace period edits (i.e., all made within the five minutes after you posted the question).

Comment: "populate the history with various alternative forms of the question and let others weigh in on the best" - that is **not** how editing is supposed to work, you're just misusing it, so no wonder it didn't "work" as you expected.

Answer (score 8):

Evidently what happened is that you made several edits within 5 minutes of posting, which never created a second revision because it was part of the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grace-period). You did not use the "rollback" button, since there is no such button on a post without a revision history.

You'd need to either edit slower or [answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321430/6083675) after making each revision.

Comment: Commenting won't work. The grace period is only broken if *someone other than the editor* comments. Note that it still gets broken if the editor themselves *answers* the question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Huh, I must be thinking of all the times I killed my own grace period by commenting on other people's posts after editing. I can't say I endorse answering your own question several times just to end the grace period though.